# How to check AWS secretsmanager rotation is completed successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

Created a secret in AWS secretsmanager, enabled automatic rotation with lambda function.
when I trigger rotation for the first time from cli, It's not completed. This is the initial state of secret when updated secret in aws console manually.

```
# aws secretsmanager list-secret-version-ids --secret-id ******
{
    "Versions": [
        {
            "VersionId": "9e82b9e2-d074-478e-83a5-baf4e578cb49",
            "VersionStages": [
                "AWSCURRENT"
            ],
            "LastAccessedDate": 1592870400.0,
            "CreatedDate": 1592889913.431
        },
        {
            "VersionId": "e32ddaf8-7f21-40e2-adf8-f976b8f3f104",
            "VersionStages": [
                "AWSPREVIOUS"
            ],
            "LastAccessedDate": 1592870400.0,
            "CreatedDate": 1592887518.46
        }
    ],
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:***********:secret:***********",
    "Name": "*******"
}
```

Now I triggered rotation from aws cli

```
aws secretsmanager rotate-secret --secret-id ******

# aws secretsmanager list-secret-version-ids --secret-id ********
{
    "Versions": [
        {
            "VersionId": "704102f3-b36d-4529-b257-0457354d3c93",
            "VersionStages": [
                "AWSPENDING"
            ],
            "CreatedDate": 1592890351.334
        },
        {
            "VersionId": "e32ddaf8-7f21-40e2-adf8-f976b8f3f104",
            "VersionStages": [
                "AWSPREVIOUS"
            ],
            "LastAccessedDate": 1592870400.0,
            "CreatedDate": 1592887518.46
        },
        {
            "VersionId": "9e82b9e2-d074-478e-83a5-baf4e578cb49",
            "VersionStages": [
                "AWSCURRENT"
            ],
            "LastAccessedDate": 1592870400.0,
            "CreatedDate": 1592889913.431
        }
    ],
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:**********:secret:********",
    "Name": "********"
}
```

Cloudwatch log stopped at this **createSecret: Successfully put secret for ARN arn:aws:secretsmanager:xxxxxxx.**. looks like only createsecret function is called.
When I rotate the secret again, Gets this output in cli

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the RotateSecret operation: A previous rotation isn't complete. That rotation will be reattempted.
```

Unable to understand what's happening. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no out-of-the-box way for that, as Secrets Manger does not have build in SNS notification nor CloudWatch Events for when rotation completes.

Thus, you have to **construct a solution yourself**, which can be done using SDK or CLI.

For CLI you can use [describe-secret](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/secretsmanager/describe-secret.html) and pull secret details in a loop. In the loop, you have to look into `AWSPENDING` and `AWSCURRENT` labels for the versions.

From the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/secretsmanager/rotate-secret.html):

> If instead the AWSPENDING staging label is **present but is not attached** to the same version as AWSCURRENT then any later invocation of RotateSecret assumes that a previous rotation request is **still in progress** and returns an error.

So basically, looking at your output:

```
        {
            "VersionId": "704102f3-b36d-4529-b257-0457354d3c93",
            "VersionStages": [
                "AWSPENDING"
            ],
            "CreatedDate": 1592890351.334
        }
```

you have a version with `AWSPENDING` label, which is **not attached to the same version** as `AWSCURRENT`. This indicates that the rotation is **in progress**.

The rotation completes, when a version is in one of the two states:

> The AWSPENDING and AWSCURRENT staging labels are attached to **the same version of the secret**, or The AWSPENDING staging label is **not attached to any version** of the secret.

Comment: I have the code which moves AWSCURRENT label to version Id of AWSPENDING in fnishSecret step. Following this template https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRotationTemplate/lambda_function.py
I"m wondering why finisheSecret step not called at all. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007180/how-to-verify-the-secrets-manager-credential-rotation-is-successful 
also seem to be of same issue.
Any idea why only createSecret step called when rotated?

Comment: @user9163519 I'm not familiar with that template. Sorry.

Comment: @Marcin Can you elaborate the solution a bit?
Do i have to remove AWSPENDING?
Will rotation complete on its own or i have to do something?

Comment: @RohitMittal I would suggest making new question specific to your use-case with details that are relevant to your requirements, errors, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203935/an-error-occurred-keypairsecretrotationschedule-received-when-doing-serverless

Answer (score 2):

Secrets Manager will publish an event via CloudTrail - 'RotationSucceeded' when there is a successful rotation.

See this for more information on how to setup a Cloudwatch alarm off that CloudTrail event  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/monitoring.html