# An error occurred: KeypairSecretRotationSchedule received when doing serverless deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

While I was deploying my application using serverless

```
npx serverless deploy
```

Error received

> ```
> > Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
> > 
> >   An error occurred: KeypairSecretRotationSchedule - Rotation is
> > blocked by pending secret version 2e0f7504-bc12-1234-3455-23f74aeabacf
> > not created by rotation. Remove the AWSPENDING staging label and
> > restart rotation. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error
> > Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID:
> > adc85817-9744-4f94-9760-abf753205e92; Proxy: null).
> ```

so, I executed

```
D:\scripts>aws secretsmanager describe-secret --secret-id dev-rohit
```

Output received

```
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:123456789012:secret:dev-rohit-jwt",
    "Name": "c2p-dev-rohit-jwt-keypair",
    "RotationEnabled": false,
    "RotationLambdaARN": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:123456789012:function:dev-rohit",
    "RotationRules": {
        "AutomaticallyAfterDays": 30
    },
    "LastRotatedDate": "2021-08-01T10:39:02.132000+05:30",
    "LastChangedDate": "2021-09-16T11:52:07.427000+05:30",
    "LastAccessedDate": "2021-09-16T05:30:00+05:30",
    "VersionIdsToStages": {
        "2e0f7504-bc12-1234-3455-23f74aeabacf": [
            "bed7",
            "AWSPENDING"
        ],
        "4ca2e0e8-56f1-4d3d-a234-3987a6e1044f": [
            "AWSPREVIOUS",
            "bed5"
        ],
        "afffc3ac-12b5-2348-3274-23ae068c3515": [
            "bed6",
            "AWSCURRENT"
        ]
    },
    "CreatedDate": "2021-03-02T10:35:55.015000+05:30"
}
```

How do I fix this issue?
Can someone please help me?
Will this rotation happen after sometime on its own or i have to do something for resolution?

Comment: How about the answer by committedandroider in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000797/aws-secrets-manager-a-previous-rotation-isn-t-complete-when-rotating-secrets .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
D:\scripts>aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id dev-rohit-jwt --version-stage AWSPENDING
```

> {
> "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:123456789012:secret:dev-rohit-jwt-keypair-BlGCxN",
> "Name": "dev-rohit-jwt",
> "VersionId": "2e0f7504-bc12-1234-3455-23f74aeabacf",
> "SecretString": "{"publicKey":"LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS0KTUlHZk1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRHTkFEQ0JpUUtCZ1FDZ3dhYmZQSmJHV3FSTXdqV05LNApyWUkrUG9DRGNHbWRsaDJicTUvbDNwV0FqUUE0SmF4ZURLbkVaWEpUc2VyOGlwMlNoRHpVbU5BR1llSUpXZitxClB5VlJlR2RMSUtiQmNGTlhSU3pRV3JzcUlkUmZwT2lsSUp4cUE1QPdk0wcmsKSTI0Y1lXN3IxVHBncGpldnNRSURBUUFCCi0tLS0tRU5EIFBVQkxJQyBLRVktLS0tLQo=","privateKey":"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"}",
> "VersionStages": [
> "kid7",
> "AWSPENDING"
> ],
> "CreatedDate": "2021-08-31T15:38:01.597000+05:30" }

```
D:\scripts>aws secretsmanager update-secret-version-stage --secret-id  dev-rohit-jwt --version-stage AWSPENDING --remove-from-version-id 2e0f7504-bc12-1234-3455-23f74aeabacf
```

> {
> "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:123456789012:secret:dev-rohit-jwt-keypair-BlGCxN",
> "Name": "dev-rohit-jwt" }

Now to test if secret key with AWSPENDING is deleted or not

```
D:\scripts>aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id dev-rohit-jwt --version-stage AWSPENDING
```

> An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the
> GetSecretValue operation: Secrets Manager can't find the specified
> secret value for staging label: AWSPENDING

Now try deployment again and it should work fine.

Special Thanks @Shimo for guidance.
Refer to answer by @committedandroider answer for more explanation [AWS secrets manager, 'A previous rotation isn’t complete' when rotating secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000797/aws-secrets-manager-a-previous-rotation-isn-t-complete-when-rotating-secrets)